# Application just hangs in between while working with threads?

Tags: java, android, ssl

Have setup an ssl connection app, have already setup connection between client and server using single thread. Since my app deals with remote desktop access, i am trying to implement threading.

Don't know why the application just stops after creating socket, it neither fails nor performs SSLhandshake. Same code when executed under single thread works smoothly, but under multi-thread its not. Have tried logcat, it couldnt help me out. Out of 10-15 tries, application works fine 1 time, but goes to not responsive mode.

Any idea where i am hitting wrong ?Here is the code. Any answer please do share.

Main activity:

```
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try{
                Log.d(TAG, "Opening RFB socket");
                rfb = new rfbProtocol(ip, port, RFB_ClientActivity.getContext());
                txt_notify.append("Connection done");
                Log.d(TAG, "RFB socket openned");
                handler.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        progress.setMessage("Connection established..\nPlease wait");
                    }
                });
                processProtocol(progress);
            }catch(Exception e){
                if(maintainConnection){
                    if(progress.isShowing())
                        progress.dismiss();
                    txt_notify.append( "Connection failure:\n" + e.getMessage() );
                    Log.d(TAG,"RFB socket failure");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
```

rfbProtocol:

```
rfbProtocol(String h, int p, Context c) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    host = h;
    port = p;
    cont = c;
    try {
        // Setup the SSL context to use the truststore and keystore
        Log.d(TAG, "Initializing SSL connection");
        SSLContext ssl_context = createSSLContext(cont);              
        SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = (SSLSocketFactory) ssl_context.getSocketFactory();
        Log.d(TAG,"Creating RFB socket");
        socket = (SSLSocket) socketFactory.createSocket(host, port);
        Log.d(TAG,"RFB Socket created");
        dataOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        dataIn = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream(), 16384));
        close = false;
        Log.d(TAG,"SSL connection done");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        throw(e);
    }
}

private SSLContext createSSLContext(final Context cont) throws Exception{
    SSLContext ssl_cont = null;
    try {
        // Setup truststore
        Log.d(TAG, "TrustStore - Initializing");   
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        InputStream trustStoreStream = cont.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.clienttruststore);
        trustStore.load(trustStoreStream, "client".toCharArray());
        trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);
        Log.d(TAG, "TrustStore - Initialized");

        // Setup keystore
        Log.d(TAG, "KeyStore - Initializing");
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        InputStream keyStoreStream = cont.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.client);
        keyStore.load(keyStoreStream, "client".toCharArray());
        keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, "client".toCharArray());
        Log.d(TAG, "KeyStore - Initialized");

        ssl_cont = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        ssl_cont.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        throw(e);
    }
    return ssl_cont;
}
```

Application just hangs after "RFB Socket created", followed by activity logged by intent in the logcat. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using Asynch task? If not may be worth to try.

Comment: @thinksteep: neither that helped me :( here is the [log file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/60536209/logcat.txt) i got when running the app on android 2.3 and the app is developed for android 2.2, i hope it doesn't matters. :(

Comment: `I/ActivityManager(159): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10100000 cmp=com.rfb.client/.RFB_ClientActivity bnds=[182,205][238,271] } from pid 159`

This thing shows up after socket is created. Don't why ? but its coming.

Comment: Solved, it was not problem from threads. I didn't manually invoked handshake at server from serversocket. Now that i have initiated handshake from server its working smooth. Thanks for your concern thinksteep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since ssl server socket is used and i have my own java host, need to initiate handshake protocol manually. This worked for me !